# Asymptotics on Golden Ratio/Fibonacci

Tags: asymptotics

Given Fibonacci is F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) for all n >= 2

Prove that for any a, b such that 1 ≤ a < φ < b we have that F(n) ∈ O(b^n
) and that
F(n) ∈ Ω(a^n
).

I'm looking for help on how to start this question

Comment: What have you tried? What do you already know about the Fibonacci numbers? In particular, do you know an explicit formula for computing $F(n)$ without computing $F(0), F(1), \ldots, F(n-1)$?